# VS code terminal process failed to launch as debugging in attached running container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, airflow, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm trying to setup Airflow debugging environment with VS code using Remote - containers plugin. What I did so far:

1. `docker-compose up` the image `apache/airflow:2.2.4` with Docker Desktop community 2.4 on macOS 10.13.6
2. Attach to the running `airflow-scheduler` container with Remote - containers plugin
3. Compose a `launch.json` file with

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Airflow Test",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    // $ which airflow
    "program": "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
      "dags",
      "test",
      "task_of_middleware",
      "2022-04-08"
    ],
    "justMyCode": true
  }
]
```

VS code pops up error below when I start debugging:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/sbin/nologin" does not exist.
```

The attached running container shows error:

```
[1382 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
[1518 ms] Container server: Error: spawn /sbin/nologin ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[1525 ms] Error: spawn /sbin/nologin ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[1530 ms] Container server: (node:11888) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I think the container runs normally since I'm able to connect to container shell via Docker Desktop and run Airflow test command. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best practice, I found a way to ease the error and make debugger run normally. Put a config into the Attached container configuration files by select **Remote-Containers: Open Container Configuration File** from the Command Palette after attaching.

```
// Container user VS Code should use when connecting
"remoteUser": "root"
```

[Reference here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container#_attached-container-configuration-files).

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having, but in order to get to the configuration file I had to connect to a folder inside the container first.